# how to "freeze" a cell in excel with a macro

Tags: excel, vba, cell, freeze

[image]

In the cell H1 you can find the statement: =J2   in it.
When you enter a value in J2, the same value should appear in H1.
When you hit the "Freeze" button, there should be a macro which freezes the cell H1 so you can type any value in J2 but the value in H2 stays.

Comment: Do you want saying to transform the existing formula in its Value? Do you also need something to be called 'unfreezing' it?

Comment: Yes, I want to add this later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert an ActiveX button on the sheet. It will automatically be named "CommandButton1". If not, use the name allocated by Excel.

Double click it and copy the next event code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("H1").HasFormula Then
        Range("H1").Value = Range("H1").Value
        Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "UnFreeze"
   Else
        Range("H1").Formula = "=J2"
        Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Freeze"
   End If
End Sub
```

When you press the button, it will freeze or unfreeze according to the cell status, and the button caption will be changed accordingly

Comment: When I insert an Active X button I get a white button which i can just double-click to see the code but I cant activate it

Comment: @Fennix 900 How do you insert it? Do you have `Developer` tab activated? If yes, you initially should press `Design Mode` button, before selecting and inserting it. Press it again, in order to make it `active`...